# Check if unknown enum has default value

Tags: c#, enums

I have a few enums and all have the first with the Name "Default".
Now I have a function where I only get an onject as Parameter so how can I check if this object is set to the first entry of the enum?
 I only know how to check if it is a enum but not what value it has.

Comment: Could you please provide a short code-sample that shows what you triy to achieve?

Comment: _"I only get an onject as Parameter"_ what kind of object, `System.Object`? If so, why? You don't know the type of enum that is passed?

Comment: Yes, I dont know the type of enum that I get, I only want to know if it is set to the first value.

Comment: Did you try to use `Enum.TryParse`?

Comment: The default value of all enums is the one with converted integer value `0`. But you may also be talking about an enum with a tag `Default` where this tag is not `0` (which is not recommended practice, but it is allowed).

Comment: There is no guaranteed way of retrieving the order that enum elements are  declared in in the source code at runtime. So, there is no way to check what the value of the first declared enum mumber is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would help I geuss

```
public static bool IsFirstEnum<T>(T enumVal) where T: System.Enum
{
    return enumVal.Equals(default(T));
}
```

PS: Please keep in mind that default Enum element is defined first with lowest Flag (Preferably 0) [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)

Ex: `enum Day {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};` where Sat is Default 
Ex: `enum Day {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};` where againg Sat is Default 
Ex: `enum Day {Sat=1, Sun=0, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};` where againg Sun is Default

If your intention is to use "Defaul" keyword then

```
public static bool IsDefaultEnum<T>(T enumVal) where T: System.Enum
{ 
    var val = typeof(T).GetField("Default").GetValue(enumVal);
    return val.Equals(enumVal);
}
```

Comment: As an asside: the enum-constraint exists only from C#7.3 upwards.

Comment: Could you please explain this "Please keep in mind that default Enum element is defined fist with lowest Flag"?

Comment: The information "default Enum element is defined first with lowest Flag" is wrong. default(SomeEnumType) will always return 0. Even if the Enumeration doesn't have an element with value 0.

Comment: `In this enumeration, the sequence of elements is forced to start from 1 instead of 0. However, including a constant that has the value of 0 is recommended.` Also `The default value of an enum E is the value produced by the expression (E)0` [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)

Comment: This code checks if the value is 0, regardless of whether this value has been assigned a tag or not, or whether this tag is the first one. In particular, for the enum `enum Day {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri}`, none of the defined tags qualify as the "default" with this code (and, indeed, none of them are!)

Comment: I added another solution for "Default" Keyword

Comment: Lower values can appear after higher values if explicitly set. Whether that's a good, bad or irrelevant thing for the question isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

If all of these default values are zero (which is the norm) then you can just cast to `int` and compare with zero. This is also the same as `default` for the given enum type.

If not and you want to use the name `"Default"` as the determining feature then you could use.

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "Default")
```

To return an object equal to `MyEnum.Default` and so on.

To obtain the first defined value you would need to use:

```
typeof(MyEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First().GetValue(null);
```

I'm not sure if it's guaranteed that the first defined value would remain the first in order, but it currently works that way.

Comment: Technically the C# standard does not make guarantees about the physical order of members for *any* type, `enum` or not, except that the declaration order is respected for assigning enum tag values and the order in which initializers are called, so no, this isn't guaranteed. Practically, it respects the order, and it needs to for things like `StructLayoutKind(LayoutKind.Sequential)`. Still, probably not something you want code to depend on (there's probably someone out there who thought it'd be neat to have an editor extension to sort enum values alphabetically or by value, which is "safe"...)

Answer (score -2):

You can cast int values into Enum values (and reversed), and the default Enum value always has a value of 0.

You can check if a returned enum is the default value by checking it's int value:

```
if((int)EnumVal == 0)
{return "Enum is default";}
```

the other way around, you can check what the default is by casting the other way around:

```
    EnumName default = (EnumName)0;
```

Comment: according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) this is not always true

Comment: default is reserved word and it cannot be used as variable :)